# Output = 0 when trying to calculate functions in a header and calling them in a main program

Tags: c++

I've been learning cpp for two days now (super beginner) and to train it, I'm trying to solve some fluid mechanics problems, since I have an engineering background. In the code I'm trying to get inputs (cin) of some variables and with them, solve all the equations necessary in a header file (to make the code shorter) and then bring the results to the main file.

So far I've only done 1 case, since the others will be similar, so I'm trying to work out the first case to know how should I go for the next ones.

For the code provided, I only showed 1 function, since the other ones look pretty much the same, with the only difference being the equation written in them.

**Main File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "fenomenos.hpp"

//Determining the case type
int case_determination(int casE){

std::cout << "Inform the case number from 1 to 6\n";
std::cin >> casE;

return casE;
}

void resol_cases(){
int casE;
if (casE == 1){

std::cout << "Inform the pipe diameter";
std::cin >> d;
std::cout << "Inform the flow rate";
std::cin >> Q;

calc_area();
calc_vel();
calc_Re();
calc_f();
calc_h1();
calc_h2();

}
}

int main() {

std::cout << "Area = " << A << " m^2\n";
std::cout << "Velocity = " << v << " m/s\n";
std::cout << "Re = " << Re << " \n";
std::cout << "f = " << f << " \n";
std::cout << "h1 = " << h1 << " m\n";
std::cout << "h2 = " << h2 << " m\n";

}
```

**Header File**

```
//Definicao das variaveis
double d;
double A;
double Q;
double h1;
double h2;
double v;
double Re;
double ke;
double f;
double rho;
double mi;
double g;
double L;
const double PI  = 3.141592653589793238463;
const double e = 2.71828;

//Area calculation

double calc_area(double A){

A = (PI*pow(d,2))/4;

return A;

}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile because `double calc_area(double A)` requires an argument, but your call `calc_area();` doesn't provide any. Moreover, your code always starts in `main`, and because you don't call any of your functions in `main`, none of them are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` function is where you need to call all your functions to get your values. `main` is the only part of the code that runs on startup, so any other functions that need running need to be called within `main`. Right now, your `main` is just printing out the statements. To run the equations, you need to run `resol_cases()` in your `main`. Like this:

```
int main() {
    resol_cases();
    std::cout << "Area = " << A << " m^2\n";
    std::cout << "Velocity = " << v << " m/s\n";
    std::cout << "Re = " << Re << " \n";
    std::cout << "f = " << f << " \n";
    std::cout << "h1 = " << h1 << " m\n";
    std::cout << "h2 = " << h2 << " m\n";

}
```

These global variables will likely default to zero at the start and are not changed unless you call the functions that change them **from** the `main`.

Another note: Inside `resol_cases()`, you need to get the case, so use this line for declaration of `casE`:

```
void resol_cases(){

    int casE = case_determination();

    …

}
```

This is how you get `casE`.
Note that the parameter is removed from the signature because the function does not use a value outside of the function to run. This also applies to your area function.

```
int case_determination(){
    int casE; // declare internal variables here
    std::cout << "Inform the case number from 1 to 6\n";
    std::cin >> casE;

    return casE;
}
```